# Generating a Nix package from a stack project

Tags: haskell, package-managers, haskell-stack, nix

I have a software application that can be built and installed with `stack`. I would like to offer a binary package as well for Linux and Mac. For this purpose I'm considering `nix`, since, among other things, it can be used in Linux and Mac. This will save me the trouble of having to maintain two package types.

After reading about how `nix` packages are defined, I would expect that a `stack` based project could be built with a configuration that would look like:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, stack }: # we need to depend on stack

stdenv.mkDerivation { 
  name = "some-haskell-package-0.1"; 
  builder = ./builder.sh; # here we would call `stack install` 
  src = fetchurl {  # ...
  };
}
```

Looking at the resources available online, I cannot find any description of how this could be done. I don't know if this means that `stack` and `nix` are not intended to be used in this way.

The only thing I could find in the manual is [how `stack` can use `nix`](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-build-a-haskell-project-using-stack), and a [`stack` to `nix`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/stack2nix) conversion tool.

I'm also open to alternatives for multi-platform packaging.

Comment: The Nix Manual has a section called "How to build a Haskell project using Stack" https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#how-to-build-a-haskell-project-using-stack . Use `haskell.lib.buildStackProject` instead of `stdenv.mkDerivation`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this recent [merge](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/30072), I am able to build and installed a simple stack project using following steps:

1. Create new `hello` project with `stack new hello`
2. Add following lines to `stack.yaml`

   ```
   nix:
     enable: true
     shell-file: default.nix
   ```
3. Create `default.nix`

   ```
   with (import <nixpkgs> { });

   haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
     name = "hello";
     src = ./.;
   }
   ```

At this point, I am able to run `nix-build` to build the project and result will be at `./result/bin/hello-exe`

If I want to install, I would run `nix-env -i -f default.nix`

---

Side note: `nix-build` will download stack's build plan every time it run.

I want to incrementally build my project while making changes so I mainly just drop in the shell and call `stack build` there.

Comment: Any ideas on how to use the latest `nix` (that includes those changes)?

Comment: @DamianNadales You could use `-I nixpkgs=/path/to/repo` flag with most `nix-*` command. If you don't want to clone [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) you can just use the snapshot url provided by github like this `nix-shell -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz -p stack`

Comment: I get the following error: derivation '/nix/store/xxx.drv' has '__noChroot' set, but that's not allowed when 'sandbox' is 'true'